# LCD not working with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd

I am a new learner on Arduino. I am trying to learn how to control the LCD. I looked in the article, ["Hello World!"](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HelloWorld), and followed the instructions but it did not work (I checked it many times). The result I got is shown below (the text is not showing).

Please help me. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Photo of LCD not displaying correctly]

Here is my code:

```c
    #include <LiquidCrystal.h>
    LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5,4,3,2);

    void setup() {
      // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
     lcd.begin(16, 2);

    lcd.print("hello, world!");
    }

    void loop() {
      // set the cursor to column 0, line 1
      // (note: line 1 is the second row, since counting begins with 0):
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      // print the number of seconds since reset:
      lcd.print(millis() / 1000);
    }
```

Comment: It could be the fact that you are not using a soldered header pins. Any slightly movement may break your connections. Do you have any male pins you can solder to LCD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 things you can try.

**1.**
If you have any male pins, solder those to the lcd screen, then stick it in the breadboard. After that you can stick the wires in the breadboard appropriately. The first time I tried this the wires were either touching or not connected enough to the lcd screen.

**2.** Double check all the connections made. This also happened to me, just make sure all the wires are in their right places.

**3.** Have you tried adjusting the potentiometer? Thats what its there for. Try turning it **slowly** both directions to adjust the background and letter brightness.

From the looks of the picture, number 3 may be your problem. Try that step first, and if it doesn't work you can try the other two. Hope this helps!